# Oracle querying view

Tags: oracle

I am having a problem with a simple query of a view. The view itself is nasty having union_all and most of its fields evaluated by functions. The problem is that even a very simple query can get the whole view evaluated which then takes forever.

To simplify my problem I have made this two queries

```
select * from horrible_view where id in (1, 2, 3); -- this works super quick
select * from horrible_view where id in (select id from my_temp_table); -- this takes forever
select * from my_temp_table t left join horrible_view h on t.id=h.id    -- this also takes forever
```

So even though my_temp_table contains the same 1, 2, 3 (3 rows with just one column) the second and third query makes the optimizer go bananas, so that the horrible view  is evaluated completly and then returns just the 3 rows are returned.

Is there anything I could do?
IE in the second example make optimizer run the "select id from my_temp_table" first and then the query.

Oracle's version is 11.2

Further info:
First off I know only a little about Oracle. (So is the Explain plan from sqlDeveloper the thing you want? If so how can you print it, its huge?) Well here is the screenshot: [here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/9gbskl.jpg)

I have created the temp table just in order to test. Its actually named TMP_R (and it has 10 rows)

Comment: To get the obvious question out of the way, are your stats up to date, particularly on `temp_table`? Does the execution plan show it's using a high value for the cardinality of that table? There are optimiser hints that might help but it depends why it's making the current decisions, so showing the execution plans for at least the first and second scenarios might help.

Comment: I added some more info in the question itself

Comment: Unless the hints are inside the base view, they might not be honored from a query against the [view.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm)